# How to replace a text saved in variable in EyeAutomate

Tags: selenium, automation

I am working in EyeStudio for EyeAutomate used for test automation. I was trying to replace a string saved in variable but in vain. What I was doing is:

Replace "{Username}" " " "-"

But it does not replace space with hyphen. However if I do this

"Azhar Ahmad" " " "-"

it replaces space with hyphen.

Any idea?